# WCF/TransactionScope/TransactionFlow in two domains

Tags: wcf, transactionscope, wcf-client

[image]

Having two domains, client in DomainA connects to WCF service in server1 and also opens a TransactionScope, (distributed) transaction flows to server1. Server1 has access to DomainB via VPN, server1 then connects to server2 and transaction flows to server2 too.
Now if the transaction gets rolled back in server2, what happened in client? Is this scenario can be managed in WCF architecture? If no, what's the solution for such scenario?

(Client has no access to server2, and DTC is also active.)

I got this exception :
**The flowed transaction could not be unmarshaled. The following exception occurred: Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed.**

Answer (score 0):

If you have DTC enabled then the flow will follow distributed transaction tenants in which all participants in the transaction must vote or agree that the transaction can be committed. If one participants fails to agree then the whole transaction will be rolled back. In your scenario, a failure to commit a transaction on server 2 will rollback the transaction.

Comment: But when transaction get rolled back in server 2, in server1 unmarshal exception occurred! 
If Client/Serber1/Server2 are all in the same domain, everything is OK. I thinks WCF has problem with transaction flow when dealing with two domains.

Comment: Can you test out DTC and ensure that it is generally working in you scenario. WCF should handle transaction response regardless of knowing about domains.

Comment: I got this exception : 
The flowed transaction could not be unmarshaled. The following exception occurred: Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed.

Comment: Did you come across this --> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5dc44d17-c99b-4a4e-8fc0-99fb39b92f91/the-flowed-transaction-could-not-be-unmarshaled?forum=windowstransactionsprogramming